# How to get list of variable names from an erubis file?

Tags: ruby, erubis

From within a Ruby script, is there a way to pragmatically obtain a list of all expected variable names and function names found in an erubis file?

For instance, how would one determine from the Eruby object that the contains the variable 'name'?

```
require 'erubis'
source = 'Hello, <%= name %>'
erb = Erubis::Eruby.new(source)
```

Comment: did you try calling ```instance_variables``` or ```methods``` ?

Comment: I attempted, but didn't notice anything useful.  I updated the original question to provide some sample source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My hackish solution:

```
# from the original question
require 'erubis'
source = 'Hello, <%= name %>'
erb = Erubis::Eruby.new(source)

# a not so great solution
vars = {}
begin
  Erubis::Eruby.new(code).result(vars)
rescue NameError => e
  puts "Found: '#{e.name}'"
  vars[e.name.to_sym] = nil
  retry
end
```

Which results in:

```
Found: 'name'
```

Comment: Good start, but it does not handle methods which causes an infinite loop.